# Points and polygon with same coordinate system do not line up in ArcMap 10

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, polygon, point

1st, I added a shapefile with projected coordinate system SL_grid_99 to Table of contents.
[image]

2nd, I added my points (excel file) to the table of contents. I displayed XY data and exported point data as shapefile. This is the coordinate system for the points:

[image]

It seems that both, point and polygon, have the same coordinate system. However, they are not lining up. As can be seen in the map, the points are in the lower left-hand corner:
[image]

How can I make the points and polygon line-up?

Comment: it seems that the point data is stored in your excel with degree coordinates, and not meters. I suppose you can try to import them once again (display xy data) and providing a wgs84 geographic as the CRS

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have re-imported the points and when displaying xy data have indicated WGS 84  UTM zone 44N but now the points are even further away. Should I also change the polygon to this CRS?

Comment: They're in decimal degree which means a geographic coordinate system, not a projected coordinate system. Try using WGS84 (EPSG:4326) instead.